# Add Paypal to Microsoft payment account, without adding a credit card

Tags: paypal, microsoft-account

Is it possible to add PayPal to your Microsoft account without adding a credit card to your PayPal account? As a youngster, I do not have a credit card and I am not planning on getting one.

Comment: Hopefully it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done. Paid apps need a valid Credit Card but without one there's no purpose of adding an account.